# What is the purpose of pre and post deployment?

Tags: deployment, release

i am new to pre and post deployment

To understand this i came across this:
“”When databases are created or upgraded, data may need to be added, changed, or deleted. Moreover, certain actions may have to occur on the database before and/or after the process completes. Deployment scripts can be used to accomplish this.””

I want to understand how this exactly works with an example

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/3006/working-with-pre-and-post-deployment-scripts/

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the site, a good example of a post deployment step is insertion of seed data.

For instance, you create a new currency table as part of the schema migration step. Then you insert the most commonly used currencies (say USD, EUR, etc.) so that they don't have to be inserted with a manual step.

Another example of post deployment step is populating data for a newly added column. For example you add a new column called `IsPremium` to the Customers table and want to set all customers with a start date > 5 years as `true`. A post deployment script is good place to do that.

Similarly scripts that run before the migration go into pre-deployment scripts. One example is locking certain table to ensure that the migration script is run only once, or setting a flag to indicate a migration is in progress.